# How are encrypted Word documents stored?

Tags: microsoft-office, encryption, format

I know that Microsoft Office files are basically just `ZIP` archives with a different file extension that contain XML files. However, when you select the "Encrypt with a password" option how are they stored, because when I try renaming one to a zip it isn't recognised as one and won't extract.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it uses some form of [Data Spaces Structure for Rights-Managed Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hope I helped.

Comment: Wow, I forgot about this question. Thanks for the link, I'll look into it a bit more when I get the chance.

Comment: Good luck. Hope to hear from you soon.